# How to get substring from string in MySQL column

Tags: mysql, substring

Have a nice day to everyone!
**Source data:** There is a conditional Log table In it there is a request column in which such a value is stored:

```
POST /user/345564523424365 HTTP/1.1
Accept:             application/json, text/plain, */*

Sec-Fetch-Dest:     empty
X-Php-Ob-Level:     1

{"status":"ready"}
```

It is necessary to get the status value without quotes.

**My solution:**

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                    SUBSTRING(Log.request FROM LOCATE("status", Log.request) + 9),
                    '"',
                    1
                ) AS status
```

We find the position of the word status via LOCATE, move the cursor by 9 characters (the number of characters from the beginning of the word status to "ready") and select everything up to the first quotation mark.

**Required result:** ready

Are there any other options for this solution, maybe there is something simpler? Thanks!

Comment: *There is a conditional Log table In it there is a request column in which such a value is stored* Does this is a multiline value stored in one column of one row?

Comment: Test this: `SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, '"', -2), '"', 1)`

Comment: Yes, all this text in one column of one row

Comment: Test the above expression or even `SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, '"status":"', -1), '"', 1)`

Comment: Maybe it's safe to read last line as json. `JSON_EXTRACT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Log.request, '\n', -1),"$.status") AS status`

Answer (score 1):

If the format of the data is always exactly like your sample; whereas the position of `{"status":"ready"}` is always at the end, then you may try:

```
SELECT 
     REGEXP_REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(val,':',-1),'[^a-zA-Z]','') AS status
...
```

or perhaps, more specific on the delimiter:

```
SELECT 
     REGEXP_REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(val,'{"status":',-1),'[^a-zA-Z]','') AS status
...
```

Use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to extract the value after `{"status":` then use `REGEXP_REPLACE()` to replace any non-alphabetical character in the `SUBSTRING_INDEX` extraction result.

Well, this is largely assuming that you're on MySQL 8+/MariaDB 10.2+ versions that supports `REGEXP_REPLACE()`.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4b5ed17818416310c092f61d9f35fbdf)

Additionally, here is an option if the value `{"status":"ready"}` is not consistently placed at the end of every data row:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(
         SUBSTRING(val, 
           LOCATE('"status"',val), 
               LOCATE('"}',val)-LOCATE('{"status"',val)),
               '"status":', -1) AS status
...
```

It's not a simpler solution but it's more convincing when you're not sure if the data is consistent or not. However, that's assuming that only the `status` information will be enclosed with curly brackets though.

[Demo 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c9cadd20d2e60e77613e414e139ee09f)

Answer (score 1):

You could match the `status` keyword and extract the corresponding value with a double `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(
           SUBSTRING_INDEX(message, '"status":"', -1), 
       '"', 1) 
FROM messages
```

Try it [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wn78ZCoXQiCqXCzsonaXNk/0).